# Sony WH-1000XM3 very bad mic quality

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, headset

I've done extensive reading and several workarounds trying to figure out why the mic of my new SONY 1000MX3 headset performs so poorly. My voice sounds like I'm talking in a tube or something.

What I've done so far:

1. I installed bluez 5.50.
2. I installed `blueman` and I can connect to my headset in a2dp profile. Sound is amazing, but as a2dp is unidirectional I have no mic.
3. If I launch Sound Settings, I go to Input -> Select Bluetooth Output SONY 1000MX3. Then the output reverts back to HSP/HFP and
   obviously sound is like a landline but mic seems to be working. When
   I talk I see the bars moving, although I should speak very loud for
   the bars to go to the far end.
4. Still with HSP/HFP selected, I launch Microsoft Teams to do a test call and record my voice. I can hear my voice but as said it sounds a bit choppy and like I'm talking from a tube or something. A deep voice with lots of bass.

I'm aware of the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1838151), but was wondering if there is any other workaround to use better quality settings for HFP/HSP. I can live with HSP/HFP during calls at work and then revert back to a2dp for my music, but the mic quality is unacceptable. I've also noticed that the headset does not appear in `alsamixer`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue on Kbuntu and the work arounds I've seen just don't work. If you use A2DP then you loose the input other than "monitor of" which is unusable, and if you turn that off and use HSP/HFP then the sounds is also poor whilst you gain an input device it still doesn't work.  I don't suppose that you have found a solution have you?

Answer (score 1):

I also have Sony WH-1000XM3 and micro's bad quality it's not related to Ubuntu. I tested it with Android mobile and another PC with Windows. On all devices mic quality is the same.